# Python 3 prompt in windows, input line limit

Tags: python, windows, cmd

I'm trying a simple program to solve a UVa question (11683 - Laser Sculpture, https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=24&page=show_problem&problem=2730)

I wrote below code as the answer (which was marked as wrong).

```
from sys import stdin

for line in stdin:
    if line.strip() == '0':
        exit(0)
    else:
        h, l = map(int, line.split()[:2])
        heights = stdin.readline()
        x = h
        heights = map(int, heights.strip().split()[:l])
        count = 0
        for height in heights:
            if height < x:
                count += (x - height)
            x = height
        print(count)
```

While debugging this, I observed that CMD python prompt has a limit on the maximum size of the input. It doesn't allow me to type after 512 characters in a single line.

[image]

Is there a way to increase this limit?

Comment: Why not use ```input()```. Dont seem to have a problem with that

Comment: Are you interactively typing these numbers at the console? Why not put the numbers (lines) in a file and use < redirection?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CMD, which is a shell that's just waiting in the background. CMD does not implement the console.

Comment: Python uses the console's high-level read (`ReadConsoleW`) with line-input mode enabled. Using a high-level cooked read simplifies the implementation for Python, but it's limited in that the console's line editor doesn't allow entering more characters than the passed buffer size (in `wchar_t` elements). Python's `_WindowsConsoleIO` class limits the buffer size to the `BUFSIZ` macro from the C runtime, which is just 512 characters. It should use a larger buffer size, but it will always be a fixed limit.

Comment: Thanks all, @lit: this competition requires me to read from standard input, so I can't use a file.

Comment: @YashShah ya, input() solved the issue. However, I'm more interested in understanding the issue here.

Comment: @ErykSun Ya I understand that it might not have anything to do with CMD, however if i use a IDE (ex: PyCharm) this does not happen. So issue comes when I run this in CMD.

Comment: I opened an issue on Python's bug tracker to update `io._WindowsConsoleIO` to support reading long lines up to 32K characters.

Comment: Ya @ErykSun, I got your point, hence the vote up,

Comment: FYI, `input()` is a separate code path from `_io.WindowsConsoleIO` that uses a 16K character buffer instead of 512 characters. I'd like to increase both to 32K, which is the maximum length of command lines and filepaths in Windows, both of which one might paste into the console.

Comment: @ErykSun, Thanks a lot for the explanation (I'm amazed by your knowledge in python and how do you know all this?) It's great if you can add the same as an answer as well, for the benefit of the others.

Comment: CPython is an open project. I've contributed to it on and off for about a decade -- mostly in terms of triaging bugs and reviewing code.